# AzureVPN Fails to Connect

Tags: keychain, vpn

I'm using AzureVPN on my Macbook Air M2. Previously, I was able to connect to VPN's normally. Later, after I got my machine replaced by Apple (for a keyboard issue), who transferred the data to a new machine, I'm not able to connect anymore. The VPN uses Azure Active Directory.

Here are the lines from the logs that I think are relevant:

```
10/26/2022 13:42:48 Error getKeyChainSecret: Failed to retrieve KeyChain secret. Status code -25300
10/26/2022 13:42:48 Warning removeClientAuthLoginCredentials: Failed to retrive previously saved ClientAuth: aad secret  for Vpn connection: ssvcs-hub-network-we-vnet, so no cleanup is needed!
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Is this a work computer configured as a managed device in Intune? If that's the case, I'd recommend that you contact your IT department as the device may need to be re-enrolled. Transferring the data is not enough, as the "Failed to retrieve previously saved ClientAuth" error suggests.

Comment: @jaume: this is my personal computer. The IT department I'm working with says they don't use certificates, which is weird!!